# Yii2.Браузер не загружает несколько изображений

Tags: php, html, yii2, apache, html-form

Есть ошибка весьма странная.Суть в том что браузер на загружает несколько изображений для поля типа файла когда установлен атрибут multiple.На сервер передается всегда один файл который загрузили последним.С чем связано такое поведение мне не ясно.
Файл модели.

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use mohorev\file\UploadBehavior;

use rico\yii2images\behaviors\ImageBehave;
 //use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

class Project extends ActiveRecord
{
public $image;
public $photos;
public $imageFiles;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'image' => [
            'class' => 'rico\yii2images\behaviors\ImageBehave',
        ]
    ];
}
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%projects}}';
}
public function rules()
{
    $tooLong = 'Поле {attribute} слишком длинное';
    return [
        ['name','string','max'=>200,'tooLong'=>$tooLong],
        ['description','string','max'=>1000,'tooLong'=>$tooLong],
        [['image'], 'file',  'mimeTypes' => ['image/jpeg','image /png'],   

         'wrongMimeType'=>'Разрешены только JPEG и PNG файлы'],
        [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'mimeTypes' =>    

         ['image/jpeg','image/png'] , 'maxFiles' => 0],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'name'=>'Название',
        'short_name'=>'Короткое название',
        'description'=>'Описание',
        'main_photo'=>'Главное фото',
        'photos'=>'Фото',
        'video'=>'Видео'
    ];
}
public function upload()
{

    $path = \Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload/store/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension;
    $this->image->saveAs($path);
    $this->attachImage($path, true);
    @unlink($path);
}
public function uploadPhotos()
{        
    $basePath =  \Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload/store/';
    foreach($this->photos as $file){
        $path = $basePath . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
        $file->saveAs($path);
        $this->attachImage($path);
        @unlink($path);
    }

}
}
```

Вьюха

```
<?php
 use yii\bootstrap\{
 ActiveForm,
 Html
 };
 use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
 ?>
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' =>   

 'multipart/form-data']])?>
  <?=$form->field($model, 'name')->textInput()?>
   <?=$form->field($model, 'description')->widget(CKEditor::className(),       

   [
   'options' => ['rows' => 6],
   'preset' => 'full'
   ]) ?>
   <?=$form->field($model,'image')->fileInput()?>
   <?=$form->field($model,'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => 
    true])?>

   <?=Html::submitButton('Сохранить',[
  'class'=>'btn btn-primary'
 ])?>
 <?php  ActiveForm::end()?>
```

Экшн контроллера

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new $this->className();
    $request = \Yii::$app->request;

    if($request->isPost)
    {
        if($model->load($request->post()))
        {
 //                $model->save(false);
//                $model->image = 
UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
//                if($model->image)
//                {
//                    $model->upload(); 
//                }
//                unset($model->image);
            $result = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');

            foreach($result as $item)
            {
                echo $item->basename;
            }
            exit();
            $model->uploadPhotos();
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create',[
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
}
```

Всегда только один файл отображается, в чем проблема ?

Answer (score -1):

Короче говоря ошибки никакой нет, это чистой воды моя глупость. При загрузке нескольких файлов нужно нажимать **Ctrl**